# pandas grouping based on conditions on other columns

Tags: pandas

```
import pandas as pd    
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A','B'])   
df['A']=['A','B','A','A','B','B','B'] 
df['B']=[2,4,3,5,6,7,8]  

df   
   A  B  
0  A  2    
1  B  4  
2  A  3  
3  A  5  
4  B  6  
5  B  7  
6  B  8 

df.columns=['id','num']  

df 
  id  num  
0  A    2  
1  B    4  
2  A    3  
3  A    5  
4  B    6  
5  B    7  
6  B    8
```

I would like to apply groupby on id column but some condition on num column
I want to have 2 columns is_even_count and is_odd_count columns in final data frame where is_even_count only counts even numbers from num column after grouping and is_odd_count only counts odd numbers from num column after grouping.

My output will be

```
   is_even_count  is_odd_count  
A  1  2  
B  3  1
```

how can i do this in pandas

Answer (score 0):

Use modulo division by `2` and compare by `1` with [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
d = {True:'is_odd_count', False:'is_even_count'}
df = df.groupby(['id', (df['num'] % 2 == 1).map(d)]).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
print (df)
num  is_even_count  is_odd_count
id                              
A                1             2
B                3             1
```

Another solution with [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
df = pd.crosstab(df['id'], (df['num'] % 2 == 1).map(d))
```

Alternative with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
a = np.where(df['num'] % 2 == 1, 'is_odd_count', 'is_even_count')
df = pd.crosstab(df['id'], a)
```